# Encryption and HMAC in a PSKC file

Tags: encryption, aes, hmac

This is the PSKC standard

https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6030.txt

In Section 6.1

```
  6.1.  Encryption Based on Pre-Shared Keys
```

They have the following

```
Plain Text = 3132333435363738393031323334353637383930
Algo = aes-128-cbc 
pkcs#5 padding
Encryption Key = 12345678901234567890123456789012
IV = 000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f
Encrypted text = ESIzRFVmd4iZABEiM0RVZgKn6WjLaTC1sbeBMSvIhRejN9vJa2BOlSaMrR7I5wSX
```

How do they get this? I tried using openssl command line

```
echo 3132333435363738393031323334353637383930 | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc  -nosalt -iv 000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f -a -pass pass:12345678901234567890123456789012
```

I get the following

```
HgFUJvBN9ztHcsIXNjvoTJJfOsoIq7XlOpdYCn+nk2TxQFrOJGhN+dYOHpFuIBQn
```

Likewise for the hmac-sha1

```
key = 1122334455667788990011223344556677889900
hmac-sha1 = Su+NvtQfmvfJzF6bmQiJqoLRExc=
```

I do it with openssl command line

```
echo  3132333435363738393031323334353637383930 | openssl sha1 -hmac 1122334455667788990011223344556677889900 | openssl enc -base64

(stdin)= eb6093578fdb69477f9a3322dcda28ce28b8aa1e

echo eb6093578fdb69477f9a3322dcda28ce28b8aa1e  | openssl enc -a -e
```

I get

```
ZWI2MDkzNTc4ZmRiNjk0NzdmOWEzMzIyZGNkYTI4Y2UyOGI4YWExZSAgDQo=
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0: you have the **wrong** CipherValue. The one you show is in MACMethod/MACKey and is the encryption 
of the MAC key, see 6.1.1. The encryption of the subject key is in Key/Data/Secret/EncryptedValue 
and is `AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0OD+cIHItlB3Wra1DUpxVvOx2lef1VmNPCMl8jwZqIUqGv`.

1: `openssl enc` in most cases, including the one you used, does **password-based encryption**.
This does not encrypt or decrypt with the "key" you specify, instead it considers that a password 
and runs it through a "stretching" or "derivation" function to produce the actual key. 
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22085107/perl-cbc-des-equivalent-in-java 
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783062/how-to-decrypt-an-encrypted-file-in-java-with-openssl-with-aes .
For "direct" encryption and decryption you must use `-K` (uppercase) with the key in hex.

2: the example data in the RFC is in **hex**, although it doesn't say so.
For the key and IV this is okay because `enc -K -iv` take hex, but the data must be binary.
Hex 313233...30 is ASCII 12345678901234567890 but with no terminating newline 
which `echo` automatically adds; preventing this varies depending on your system and/or shell, which 
you don't specify, so I use `perl` instead.

3: XMLenc data for block/CBC contains the (actual binary) **IV concatenated** with 
the ciphertext, with the combined *result* encoded in base64.

Thus (with binmode because I tested partly on Windows):

  `echo $k
  12345678901234567890123456789012
  echo $i
  000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f
  echo $i |\
  perl -ne "open O,'>temp';binmode O;print O map{pack('H2',$_)} ($_=~/(..)/g)" 
  # that puts the binary IV at the beginning of temp
  perl -e "print '12345678901234567890'" |\
  openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -K $k -iv $i >>temp
  # that APPENDS the encryption of the data to temp
  openssl base64 <temp
  AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0OD+cIHItlB3Wra1DUpxVvOx2lef1VmNPCMl8jwZqIUqGv`

4: MAC is computed on the **encrypted** value; also `dgst -hmac` takes the key as actual bytes (not hex) 
in a C string, but the MAC key in this example contains a null byte which is impossible in a C string.
If you *really* want, you can do the HMAC as two hashes with tweaks of the key:

  `echo $h |\
  perl -ne "open O,'>pad1';binmode O;$_=~s/[[:space:]]//g;\
  $_.='0'x(128-length($_));print O map{pack 'C',hex($_)^0x36}($_=~/(..)/g)"
  echo $h |\
  perl -ne "open O,'>pad2';binmode O;$_=~s/[[:space:]]//g;\
  $_.='0'x(128-length($_));print O map{pack 'C',hex($_)^0x5C}($_=~/(..)/g)"
  cat pad1 temp |openssl sha1 -binary -out tmp1
  cat pad2 tmp1 |openssl sha1 -binary -out tmp2
  openssl base64 <out2
  Su+NvtQfmvfJzF6bmQiJqoLRExc=`

And there you are.

Comment: Just FYI - I could also avoid the binmode/perl stuff by using the following  `for %i in (000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f) do (echo/|set /p="%i") | xxd -p -r temp` I have xxd from my vim install on windows

Comment: that's actually  `xxd -p -r > temp`

Comment: I have another similar question (actually the opposite) - http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/21084/decrypting-the-data-in-a-pskc-file - please take a look if you get the time.

Comment: For a hex value you shouldn't need to drop the newline (or other whitespace) `xxd -r` should discard it anyway. For the value(s) where newline matters, `set /p` is indeed a clever way to omit newline in Windows, but you don't need the `for` just `echo/ | set /p="12345678" >file`; you do need the quotes! I commented on #21084.